# Strategy for a self-retaining and self-releasing object

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns, memory-management

I need to implement a bit of functionality that can be used from a few different places in an application. It's basically sending something over the network, but I don't need it to be attached to any particular view - I can communicate everything to the user by UIAlertViews.

What I would like to do is encapsulating the functionality in an object (?) that can maintain it's own state for a while and then disappear all by itself. I've read in several similar topics that it's generally not advised to have an object that retains and then releases itself, but on the other hand you have singletons which apart from the fact that they never get released, are very similar in nature. You don't need to keep reference to them just to use them properly. In my situation however I feel it woud be somewhat wasteful to create a singleton and then keep it alive for something that takes a few seconds to execute.

What I came up with is a static dictionary local to the class, that keeps unique references to the instances of the class, and then, when an instance is done with its task, it performs selector 'removeObjectForKey' after delay which removes the only existing reference and effectively kills the object. This way I keep only a dictionary in memory which for the most time is empty anyway.

The question is: are there any unexpected side effects of such a solution that I should be aware of and are there any other good patterns for described situation?

Comment: If you share your same data from different classes, you can use Notification to post that information to all of them. Or you can write that data into somfile(plist can be one of them). Or even a singleton will do the work. It is upto you, which Design Pattern you follow.

Answer (score 0):

So basically instead of a persistent object of your own class, you've got a persistent object of type `NSDictionary`?  How does that help matters?  Is your object unusually large?  If you are making your codebase more complicated for the sake of a few bytes, that's not a good tradeoff.

Especially now ARC is commonplace, this kind of trickery is usually not a good idea.  Have you measured how much memory a singleton approach takes and found it to be a problem?  Unless you have done this, use a singleton.  It's simpler code, and all other things being equal, simpler code is far better.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's a tradeoff and I'm not entirely happy with it either. Also I didn't measure the exact footprint and I believe it's actually not **much** larger than NSDictionary in absolute terms, so I can follow your suggestion in this particular case, but the whole idea of keeping something like that forever feels ugly to me, is not scalable, etc. Also I get that what I did is a kind of trickery but again this is only a feeling and I'd feel better if I knew what kind of risk I actually take :-)

Comment: Also in the suggestions I found a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240595/self-destructing-singleton-design-pattern-ios.

Comment: Whether it's your class or `NSDictionary`, you're keeping something forever in either case.  If you haven't measured it, what basis do you have for saying that it's larger than `NSDictionary`?  What do you mean that it isn't scalable?  What is the etc?  It really sounds like you're tying yourself in knots over nothing.  You should not do this unless you actually have a real problem to solve.